# Second-order derivative wrt. vector

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have a scalar function $f(\mathbf{x})$, where its argument $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector. I am Taylor-expanding $f$, so I have to find

$$
\mathbf{c}^2\frac{d^2}{d\mathbf{x^2}}f(\mathbf{x})
$$

where $\mathbf{c}$ is another vector. In the case where it is only the first derivative, I know it is

$$
\mathbf{c}\frac{d}{d\mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{c}\cdot (\nabla f) = c_idx_if(\mathbf x)
$$

But how does the second derivative with respect to a vector look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be a little bit careful with your notation: $\mathbf{c}^2$ is an abuse, since it doesn't really make sense to square a vector! The second derivative is actually a *matrix* and it is being hit on both sides by $\mathbf{c}$.

More specifically, the second-order expansion of $f$ is
$$f(x+c) \approx f(x) + c^T \nabla f(x) + \frac{1}{2}c^T\left(\nabla^2f\right) c$$
where $\nabla^2f$ is the *Hessian* of $f$, i.e. the matrix of second partial derivatives.

Intuitively, $\left(\nabla^2 f\right)c$ measures how the gradient of $f$ is changing in the $c$ direction, so the full term $c^T\left(\nabla^2 f\right)c$ measures how the change of $f$ is changing in the $c$ direction.